# Windows silent installation with file parameter

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameter-passing, nsis, silent-installer

I'm trying to make a silent installation through a Windows Batch script with a file parameter, but I'm not being able to do it.
I have a file (params.txt) which contains the parameters that should be input during the installation (such as path, choices etc).

Obs.: It may also be by PowerShell.

I have something similar in Linux, which is pretty easy:

```
.../installer.sh < .../params.txt
```

But I'm trying in many different ways, with NSIS, MSI. But none of them seens to solve my problem with these parameters.
The closest that I've got was

```
C:\installer.exe /S
```

indeed its make the installation with the default parameters, but I would like to specify them through my file.

I've made many researches, even here in stackoverflow, but nothing that solves my problem.

Content of my params.txt file:

```
yes
no
C:\Software\MySoftware
yes
no
no
no
```

The installation prompts a few questions, and the file contains the answers that I need to give during the installation.

Also, the installer was generated using **NSIS** (**Nullsoft Scriptable Install System**) .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a batch file? Are you executing multiple installers? Are you executing installers you did not write?

Comment: This is not a batch problem. You might get a list of parameters to pass on the command line by executing "Installer.exe /?". If that doesn't help you will need to check with the author of Installer.exe to find out that information as it depends on what your installer accommodates for parameters. Then you will probably need to do something like Installer.exe /S /v"/qb INSTALLDIR=Drive:\DesiredFolder SOMEOTHERPARM=Something NEXTPARM=SomethingElse etc". Most likely you will be passing these parameters on the command line rather than in a file

Comment: The answer will differ depending on what kind of installer. Is this an MSI, InstallScript, or something else?

Comment: @Anders This script will be executed automatic daily. The idea of creating this is to make the installation, with parameters, automatic and headless.

Comment: @RGuggisberg Is there any way to use this passing parameters but without nothing the names of them? Cause actually, the installer only popoups the questions and I would like to use it as answers. I add a little more detail about the txt file in the post.

Comment: @Superbob It's created using NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) .

Comment: The idea with the /S (Silent) is that the install is SILENT (does not display pop ups). It does not display the pop ups because you provide the parameters. That being said, that only works if the installer was set up to accommodate  this and you know what those parameters are. What did 'C:\Installer.exe /?' show you? Is it possible for you to modify the installer with NSIS? If you are lucky and all the "yes/no" answers are the default you may not need to pass them as parameters.

Comment: @RGuggisberg When I try the "inst.exe /?" the installation screen opens normally like I had executed normally.
But in the end, I've just installed with /S and create a script to fix the installation since I cannot change the default value.
Thank you very much all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS supports the `/S` and `/D=c:\installpath` parameters [by default](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusage), support for anything else has to be provided by the install author.

Install authors can check for specific parameters and/or a answer file:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section

; Command-line parameter:
${GetParameters} $0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $0 "/Something" $1
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    ; Do Something
${Else}
    ; Do something else?
${EndIf}

; Answer .INI file:
Var /Global AnswerFile
StrCpy $AnswerFile $ExePath -4
StrCpy $AnswerFile "$AnswerFile.ini"
ReadIniStr $0 $AnswerFile "Options" "OtherPath"
${If} $0 != ""
  File "/oname=$0\file.ext" "c:\mysource\fileForOtherPath.ext"
${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you @Anders.
I really believe that your answer answers my question, the only thing is that we have to have the name of the parameters during the installation. In my case I don't have it, but once you do your script works.

Comment: GetParameters gives you the command-line, you can parse this string any way you want.